validation process in django serializer
I have a question
class RegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if User.objects.filter(username=validated_data['username']).exists():
            raise ValidationError('ushbu username mavjud!')
        if User.objects.filter(email=validated_data['email']).exists():
            raise ValidationError("ushbu email mavjud!")
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        return user

this message given for the first username in this serializer:
if User.objects.filter(username=validated_data['username']).exists():
    raise ValidationError('ushbu username mavjud!')

it works, but the validation message for the email does not appear:
if User.objects.filter(email=validated_data['email']).exists():
    raise ValidationError("ushbu email mavjud!")

instead, drf from its default message:
 "email": [
    "user with this email already exists."
  ]

Why is it being used?
i expected validation error given inside serializer

This issue is due to the fact that DRF has built-in validation for the email field in the User model, which is being triggered before your custom validation logic.
To override the default validation message and ensure that your custom validation logic is applied, you need to handle the email validation in the validate method of the RegisterSerializer.
This is the code.
class RegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

    # Overriding the validate method
    def validate(self, data):
        # Custom validation for username
        if User.objects.filter(username=data['username']).exists():
            raise ValidationError({'username': 'ushbu username mavjud!'})

        # Custom validation for email
        if User.objects.filter(email=data['email']).exists():
            raise ValidationError({'email': 'ushbu email mavjud!'})

        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        return user

I hope this will solve your issue.

Here is another approach to send custom error message of validating email. Basically.DRF automatically validates fields based on the model constraints (like unique=True for email).If you want to send custom error message you have to override this behavior.
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

    # Custom email validation
    def validate_email(self, value):
       if User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
          raise ValidationError("ushbu email mavjud!")  # Custom message
       return value

    # further code here....

